# exporting a CSV file which includes categories, images, and products

Tags: image, csv, categories, product, migrate

I want to create a CSV so I can migrate all my products images and categories from one domain on an opencart site to a new domain on my wordpress site, can anyone tell me how to do this task please -many thanks?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [export/import tool](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=17http://)

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following SQL queries. for full script refer my tutorial.
https://www.pearlbells.co.uk/export-opencart-product-csv/

```
$sql = "SELECT p.product_id as Id, model, p.sku, upc, quantity,stock_status_id,image,manufacturer_id,shipping,"
        . "price,weight,weight_class_id,length_class_id,subtract,minimum,status,name,tag,"
        . "meta_title,meta_description,meta_keyword, pd.description as description"
        . " FROM oc_product p LEFT JOIN oc_product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id)"
        . " WHERE  pd.language_id = '1' GROUP BY p.product_id ORDER BY pd.name ASC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

For Categories :

```
    $sql = 'SELECT category_id,name,description,meta_title,meta_keyword,meta_description FROM oc_category_description ORDER BY name ASC ';
```